# log in and brute force: CAPTCHA -vs- sleep(1)

Tags: security, authentication, captcha, sleep, brute-force

What's better to use against brute force method (when 3+ unsuccessful trials to login within the last let's say 5 minues) and why - display CAPTHA or using sleep(let's say 1 second)?

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://s.tk/security.

Comment: This question makes no sense. Better how? To whom? Under what conditions? Is this for the web? Can the CAPTCHA be bruteforced in under 1 second? Is the client truly locked out, or is the one connection just frozen?

Comment: I don't understand why I got -1 for this question. I beleive I've clearly described the situation: what's better to use for users when users make 3 unsuccessful trials to log in into members area. Yes, this is for the web. Can GOOGLE CAPTHA be bruteforced in unders 1 second? I belive the answer is no, it is not. Or, they would have make it stronger. If you better know, I would appreciate if you share you thoughts answering this question. I can't verify if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion a good CAPTCHA is probably better than a one second delay.  But it must be a **good** CAPTCHA (meaning very difficult to solve with a machine but still easy for a human to solve).  Even if the machine on the other end can solve your CAPTCHA, it is likely to take much more than a second to solve a good CAPTCHA unless the attacker has extraordinary computing power at their disposal.

That said, you may wish to balance that against the annoyance that CAPTCHAs tend to elicit in users.  Of course, these are users who have mistyped their password three times or have forgotten their password, and hopefully that is a minority of users (although no doubt it will happen more than you wish).

Also, things may change if you do exponential (or whatever the correct mathematical term is) delays.  So, the first delay is 1 second, the second is 2 seconds, the third is 4 seconds, the next is 8 seconds, etc.  That would be much more effective than using 1 second delays only.

And, of course, there's no reason you can't do both a CAPTCHA and a delay, which is what I would recommend if you are worried about brute forcing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please confirm (I hope that's not another question) server is not hanging when sleep is used (so the sleep method is OK to solve this question as well). 1,2,4,8 seconds (x2) or x1.15 f.e. is a good idea. Thank you for you answer. I've received -1 for my question, but thank you very much for your answer.